# citrus waitFor().file fails to read a file

Tags: citrus-framework

I’m trying to use waitFor() in my Citrustest to wait for an output file on disk to be written by the process I’m testing. I’ve used this code

```
outputFile = new File “/esbfiles/blesbt/bl03orders.99160221.14289.xml");
waitFor().file(outputFile).seconds(65L).interval(1000L);
```

after a few seconds, the file appears in the folder as expected. The user I’m running the test code as has permissions to read the file. The waitFor(), however, ends in a timeout.

```
09:46:44 09:46:44,818 DEBUG dition.FileCondition| Checking file path '/esbfiles/blesbt/bl03orders.99160221.14289.xml'
09:46:44 09:46:44,818 WARN  dition.FileCondition| Failed to access file resource 'class path resource [esbfiles/blesbt/bl03orders.99160221.14289.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist'
```

What could be the problem? Can’t I check for files outside the classpath?

Comment: where on your disk is the target folder located exactly? The leading / in your path may result in an absolute file path on unix operation system which may not be your target. Removing the leading file path separator will result in a file path relative to your project working directory.

Comment: This is the exact path of the file: **/esbfiles/blesbt/bl03orders.99160221.14289.xml**. So it's located in a subfolder of a folder in the root of the filesystem. The file is readable with java.io.File when given the path in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a bug in Citrus. Citrus is working with the file path instead of the file object and in combination with Spring's PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver this causes Citrus to search for a classpath resource instead of using the absolute file path as external file system resource.

You can fix this by providing the absolute file path instead of the file object like this:

```
waitFor().file(“file:/esbfiles/blesbt/bl03orders.99160221.14289.xml")
         .seconds(65L)
         .interval(1000L);
```

Issue regarding broken file object conversion has been opened: https://github.com/christophd/citrus/issues/303

Thanks for pointing to it!